# reference request - Practice problems for probability theory.

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, random-variables, random, bit-strings

I need some good probability theory practice problems on the following topics -

- Binary strings ( Bit strings )
- generating random permutations using bit strings
- Coin toss problems where each toss is considered as a random bit. Problems such as simulating a biased coin using least number of random bits.

Comment: Rosenthal probability?